# resize plugin with scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have scrolling enabled on a div with other divs drawn on it. I want to resize the overlay divs to mark things on the underlying div. I am using the jqueryui resizable functionality. It is working fine when the underlying div is at scroll 0,0 position, but when the div is scrolled and then resizing is done the overlay div jumps around without rhyme and reason!.
 Please help me with this. Any suggestions are welcome.

This is the code for testing the condition. Sorry could not create fiddle for it

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<HTML>
 <HEAD>
  <TITLE> Resizable </TITLE>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Styles/jquery.ui.resizable.css" />

  <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery.tools.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-layout.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-ui.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="Jquery/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="Jquery/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="Jquery/jquery.ui.mouse.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="Jquery/jquery.ui.resizable.js"></script>


  <style type="text/css">
   #insertfile {
    overflow: auto;
    position: absolute;
    width:200px; height:100px;
    border: 2px solid #000;
}
td { width: 50px; height: 50px; text-align: center; }
  </style>

  <script type="text/javascript">
   $(function() {
    var currentTd = $('td#currentId');
    var scrtop = currentTd.position().top;
    var scrleft = currentTd.position().left;
    $('#insertfile').animate({
        scrollTop: scrtop,
        scrollLeft: scrleft
    }, 400);

    var top = $(currentTd).position().top;
    var left = $(currentTd).position().left;
    var bottom = $(currentTd).position().top + $(currentTd).height() - $(currentTd).position().top;

    var right = $(currentTd).position().left + $(currentTd).width() - $(currentTd).position().left;


    $("<div id='frontLayer' class='front'></div>").insertAfter('.tableData');

//    var frontDiv = document.getElementById('frontLayer');

    $('#frontLayer').css({
        'border': '3px solid #f00',
        'position': 'absolute',
        'z-index': 2,
        'top': top + 'px',
        'left': left + 'px',
        'height': bottom + 'px',
        'width': right + 'px'
    });

    $('#frontLayer').resizable({
        handles: 'n,e,s,w',
    });

});
  </script>
 </HEAD>

 <BODY>
  <div id='insertfile'>
<table border='1px' class='tableData'>
    <tr><td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
    </tr>
        <tr><td>9</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>11</td>
        <td>12</td>
    </tr>

        <tr><td>9</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>11</td>
        <td>12</td>
    </tr>
        <tr><td>9</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>11</td>
        <td>12</td>
    </tr>
        <tr><td>9</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>11</td>
        <td>12</td>
    </tr>
        <tr><td>9</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>11</td>
        <td>12</td>
    </tr>
        <tr><td>9</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>11</td>
        <td>12</td>
    </tr>
        <tr><td>9</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>11</td>
        <td>12</td>
    </tr>
        <tr><td>9</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>11</td>
        <td>12</td>
    </tr>
        <tr><td>9</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>11</td>
        <td>12</td>
    </tr>
        <tr><td>9</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>11</td>
        <td>12</td>
    </tr>
        <tr><td>9</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>11</td>
        <td>12</td>
    </tr>
        <tr><td>9</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>11</td>
        <td>12</td>
    </tr>
        <tr><td>9</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>11</td>
        <td>12</td>
    </tr>
        <tr><td>9</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>11</td>
        <td>12</td>
    </tr>
        <tr><td>9</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>11</td>
        <td>12</td>
    </tr>
        <tr><td>9</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>11</td>
        <td>12</td>
    </tr>
        <tr><td>9</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>11</td>
        <td>12</td>
    </tr>
        <tr><td>9</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>11</td>
        <td>12</td>
    </tr>
        <tr><td>9</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>11</td>
        <td>12</td>
    </tr>
        <tr><td>9</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td id='currentId'>scroll to me</td>
        <td>12</td>
    </tr>
        <tr><td>9</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>11</td>
        <td>12</td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td>13</td>
        <td>14</td>
        <td>15</td>
        <td>16</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</div>
 </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Please include the scripts mentioned and run it on mozilla.
Thanks

Comment: will try but it will take time to isolate only the resize code from a big file

Comment: I have posted the code. Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Found a workaround but does not seem elegant. I added resize handler code to check all possible resizing, for e.g. if top has been modified , if only height has been modified, if left has been modified and so on. For the condition i am adding the scrolltop of the outer div to the values. This gives me mostly right results (few still have to be done). But overall this seems like I am writing too much of code for using an already developed plugin. So overall i seem to be doing all the resizing by myself and only value add is the smooth motion of the div!!
 Also found a drag Resize pure javascript code on twinhelix which does not get affected by the scrolling of the container.
  Please let me know if this solution seems inevitable or unnecessary! Any other solution/ suggestion is welcome.